# How to completely customize Bokeh (Python 3) appearance beyond figure themes

Tags: python, css, themes, bokeh

I am building a web frontend using Bokeh and the appearance of figures is customizable through themes (`bokeh.themes.Theme`), which is cool. But the rest of the page (widgets) seems to be another story. I tried using templates with a custom CSS file, for example:

```
/* styles.css */
.bk, .bk-btn, .bk-btn-default, bk-input {
    font-size: 3.0em;
    color: red;
}
```

My input shows in red but the font size is unchanged. It seems Bokeh overrides my styles with its JS.

How to achieve complete style customization of all Bokeh widgets?

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress after I found [this](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/changing-font-size-in-widget-and-tabs/3317/2)

I managed to increase the font size of input and button widgets using the `css_classes` property. This is the Python code:

```
# [...]
coin_textbox = self.coin_textbox = TextInput(placeholder="Coin", css_classes=["big_stuff"])
update = Button(label="Update", css_classes=["big_stuff"])
# [...]
```

Then my `styles.css` looks like this now:

```
.big_stuff .bk-input, .big_stuff .bk-btn {
    font-size: 2.0em;
    font-family: mono;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    background-color: #555565;
}
body{
background-color: #333339;
}
```

So now the widgets big (and dark (I am building a dashboard to see on mobile phone))

The CSS classes names `bk-btn` and `bk-input` can be obtained using the inpector from the web browser (`Ctrl+Shift+C` in Firefox).